# Changing color of jqplot series based on label

Tags: jqplot

I have a chart, and there is one series that in some cases I want to render in black. I generate the chart, and then I'm doing this:

```
for (i = 0; i < chart.series.length; ++i) {
    if (chart.series[i].label == 'Failures') {
        chart.series[i].color = '#000000';
    }
}
```

But it is not changing the color. I verified in the debugger that the if is true and the assignment is getting executed and the color field of that series is #000000. What is the proper way to do something like this?

Comment: Are your series dynamic or fixed?

Comment: They're dynamic. I found another way to do this. Before I create the series I find the ones I want black and I set the appropriate row in my seriesColors array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this before I create the chart:

```
   for (i = 0; i < series.length; ++i) {
        if (series[i][0][series[i][0].length-1].type == 'Failures') {
            seriesColors[i] = '#000000';
        }
    }
```